# How do you link Google Remarketing with Magento 2?

Tags: magento2

I have added my google remarketing tag into my Magento 2 head:

```
'ecomm_pagetype': 'replace with value',
'ecomm_prodid': 'replace with value',
'ecomm_totalvalue': 'replace with value',
'user_id': 'replace with value'
```

Do I need to enter something in 'replace with value' or does Magento 2 do this? If so... what do I enter?

My merchant feed says products are available for remarketing.

But my tag assistant says my products are not valid.

Here is my feed:
https://aimont.co.uk/media/feed/aimont-google.xml

The item group IDs in the feed, match exactly with those in my merchant centre. So why is it still displaying as products not valid?

[Merchant image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0cPtv.png)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to pass data from your Magento 2 to JS variables, you can use free extension to get that works https://github.com/business-factory/roi-hunter-easy-magento2-plugin